# How to check that current time is in USA timezone

Tags: c#

I am able to get the current time using `DateTime time = DateTime.Now;` but I want to compare this time to `TimeZoneInfo` to get the same time with a provided UTC offset for the United States.

Basically, I want to know that the provided time is within one of the six timezones associated with the United States (including Hawaii and Alaska).

Comment: The United State, counting Hawaii and Alaska, is at least 6 time zones wide.  Are you referring to only the continental US?

Comment: The USA doesn't really own time zones; what you really want to know is if the interestedTime lies somewhere from UTC -5 to UTC -10 inclusive. Note that this is 6 time zones. If you exclude Hawaii and Alaska, then you have 4 zones from UTC -5 to UTC -8.

Comment: How can we help? It sounds like you already know what you want to do... just do it.

Comment: Made some edits.. let me know if this is correct or not.

Comment: @Bob2Chiv: ...UTC-4 -- UTC-9/7 during summer (DST).

Comment: @josh3736 I don't think Hawaii observes DST, so it would still be UTC-10

Comment: @ all, how do i compare my time to 6 timezone? if one one them is true then i am sure that it's USA

Comment: @josh3736 and @psubsee2003 thanks ;-) @vir_28 Sounds like it'd be fairly straight-forward if you had the UTC time, though you need to be careful of DST. I'm not sure how this incorporates `TimeZoneInfo` however. Good luck!

Comment: @vir_28 Instead of editing your original question you should revert the edit and create a new question for your new question. You should not edit a question to change the meaning in its entirety. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you already know what you need.

`var currentTime = DateTime.Now();` returns the current system time.

`var zone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;` will give you the current system time zone.  You just then need to compare the time zone to time zones in the United States (UTC-5 to UTC-10 during Standard (winter) time, and UTC-4 to UTC-10 for Daylight Savings (Summer) time.

However, just looking at your comment, just because the time falls within one of the timezones in the United States does not mean it is in the United States.  There are plenty of countries in North and South America that have the same time zones.

Comment: This is what I was trying to allude to; but I was not familiar with `TimeZoneInfo`; +1 Kudos; I was trying to get the offset using
`DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()`

Comment: @psubsee2003 ,I agreee! seriously i'm in trouble!! i'm creating an application in windows phone 7 , and i want to display current country name there !

Comment: @vir_28 I've never done any Win7 phone dev, but I would think it would be easier to access the GPS information and do some reverse geocoding to get the location

Comment: @psubsee2003, it will make my app more complex , better, i will restric my app to few country for marketplace :P and will do more R and D

Answer (score 2):

This should get you what you want, and serve as an example how to get other time zones.

```
class Program
{
    static void PrintTime(string timeZoneId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( 
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, 
                timeZoneId).ToShortTimeString() +
            " is the time in " + timeZoneId);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        PrintTime("Hawaiian Standard Time");
        PrintTime("Alaskan Standard Time");
        PrintTime("Pacific Standard Time");
        PrintTime("US Mountain Standard Time");
        PrintTime("Central Standard Time");
        PrintTime("US Eastern Standard Time");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understnd you issue, you can get it from the internet. You check the function below.

```
        DateTime DT = GetNISTDate(true);
        MessageBox.Show(DT.ToString());

    public static DateTime GetNISTDate(bool convertToLocalTime)
    {
        Random ran = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        DateTime date = DateTime.Today;
        string serverResponse = string.Empty;
        // Represents the list of NIST servers  
        string[] servers = new string[] {  
                     "64.90.182.55",  
                     "206.246.118.250",  
                     "207.200.81.113",  
                     "128.138.188.172",  
                     "64.113.32.5",  
                     "64.147.116.229",  
                     "64.125.78.85",  
                     "128.138.188.172" 
                      };

        // Try each server in random order to avoid blocked requests due to too frequent request
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                // Open a StreamReader to a random time server  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(servers[ran.Next(0, servers.Length)], 13).GetStream());
                serverResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();

                // Check to see that the signiture is there  

                if (serverResponse.Length > 47 && serverResponse.Substring(38, 9).Equals("UTC(NIST)"))
                {
                    // Parse the date  
                    int jd = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(1, 5));
                    int yr = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(7, 2));
                    int mo = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(10, 2));
                    int dy = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(13, 2));
                    int hr = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(16, 2));
                    int mm = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(19, 2));
                    int sc = int.Parse(serverResponse.Substring(22, 2));

                    if (jd > 51544)
                        yr += 2000;
                    else
                        yr += 1999;
                    date = new DateTime(yr, mo, dy, hr, mm, sc);

                    // Convert it to the current timezone if desired  
                    if (convertToLocalTime)
                        date = date.ToLocalTime();
                    // Exit the loop  
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                /* Do Nothing...try the next server */
            }
        }
        return date;
    }
```